# Angular display single http response

Tags: json, angular, web-services

I'm struggling by displaying data from a single JSON respone with angular.
I've created a class for the data interndata.model.ts

```
export class Interndata {
humidity: number;
temperature: number;

constructor(humidity:number, temperature:number) {
    this.humidity = humidity;
    this.temperature = temperature;
  }
```

}

For this I crated a service interndata.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Interndata } from './interndata.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterndataService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

 public getDisplayData(): Observable<Interndata[]>{
       return this.http.get<Interndata[]>('http://192.168.0.110:8080/process');
      }
 }
```

My JSON response from the webservice is this:

> {"humidity": 49.099998474121094, "temperature": 24.899999618530273}

The class AppComponent shall get then the data regulary and update ngx-gauge to display the data.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxGaugeModule } from 'ngx-gauge';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { concatMap, map, merge, switchMap, tap, delay, skip } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { concat, of, Observable, BehaviorSubject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { Interndata } from './interndata.model';
import { InterndataService } from './interndata.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})



export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

interndata = new Array<Interndata>();
title = 'Home Automation Monitor Service';
tempValue = 0;
humValue = 0;
gaugeType = "semi";
tempLabel = "Temperatur";
tempAppendText = "°C";
gaugeThick = 25;
gaugeForegroundColor = "#000000";
gaugeBackgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
tempMin = 0;
tempMax = 30;
humLabel = "Luftfeuchtigkeit";
humAppendText = "%";
humMin = 0;
humMax = 100;
constructor(private servinterdata : InterndataService){
    servinterdata.getDisplayData().subscribe((res) => {
        this.interndata = res;
        console.log(this.interndata);
    });
}

ngOnInit () {

}
```

}

I do not know how I can use the data from the JSON response. Console.log returns the JSON as string.

```
this.interndata.humidity
```

returns undefined. How can access the data I get from the JSON response?

Comment: did you check the developer tool and see what kind of respond do you get ?

Comment: `console.log(res);` what does print

Comment: You have typed of the response as an array ```Interndata[]``` perhaps this is what you want but in that case the json must be an array like this. ```[{"humidity": 49.099998474121094, "temperature": 24.899999618530273}]```

Comment: If angular parses a single object correctly (no reason why they should but you never know :) access the data like so ```this.interndata[0].humidity```

Comment: @NathanielJohnson the method mark as it s will return an array not a single object maybe [{}] is the result

Comment: @malbarmawi console.log(res); returns the JSON string provided as quote in my question

Comment: @IrgendwPointer is the api return  an array or single object ?

Comment: @malbarmawi The response as shown in Chromium `"{\"humidity\": 48.29999923706055, \"temperature\": 25.299999237060547}"`

Comment: @IrgendwPointer have you try Jbluehdorn answer 

Comment: @malbarmawi Yes I did, but had no affect.

Comment: ```public getDisplayData(): Observable<Interndata[]>``` says return an Observable of an array of Interndata  The Observable is not the actual return value once you get it in ```subscribe``` so it is, in fact, an array.

Comment: where is `this.interndata.humidity` undefined? Also, if you expect your data to be an instance of your class, it's not :)

Answer (score 1):

If its returning a string, `this.interndata = JSON.parse(res)` should get you a nice javascript object. If that doesn't work, let me know and we can try something else.

Comment: HttpClient class will parse the response by default 

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking but in the question they said "Console.log returns the JSON as string." which seemed odd but if that's the case, an easy fix. I'm wondering if they mean the keys are strings and if so, it should all be accessible via res["humidity"] or whichever key they need.

Comment: it 's very hard to know the problem here ,still the quetion has some blurry it seem everything working but we are here just guesing  , if the users show my result maybe we can figert it out 

Comment: you was correct , but I still don't know how this is happen 

Answer (score 0):

```
public getDisplayData(): Observable<Interndata[]>
```

says to return an Observable of an Array of Interndata.  This means that you have Typed the response as an array Interndata[] perhaps this is what you want but in that case the json must be an array like this.

```
[{"humidity": 49.099998474121094, "temperature": 24.899999618530273}]
```

and would be accessed like this:

`this.interndata[0].humidity`

To help debug this you can add an error handler like this

```
public getDisplayData(): Observable<Interndata[]> {
       return this.http.get<Interndata[]>('http://192.168.0.110:8080/process')
        .pipe<Interndata[]>(
          catchError(err=>console.log('Err: '+err))
        );
}
```

This is a good tutorial on Error Handling in RxJx: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/

Comment: Unfortunatetly, this does not work either. I tried also to remove the array in the class and in the method. `constructor(private servinterdata : InterndataService){
        servinterdata.getDisplayData().subscribe(res => 
            console.log("Result" + res.humidity),
            err => console.log('HTTP error',err)
        );
    }` The response is then Resultundefined

Comment: My suspician is that your service is mislabeling the response type as text.  You can check this by opening the debug window in your browser Ctrl+Shift+I typically in FF and Chrome, and perusing the network tab.  Refresh will be necessary. Also, I made a change to my answer (pipe need to be typed as well)